# Tags: How to get the list of my created tags till now

Tags: discussion, tags

I just wanted to know that is there any way to get and view the list of my created **tags** during asking and editing questions.

There is tag option in site which list all the tags but I am looking for some thing like **"My created tags"**.

Any help, experience and knowledge sharing would be highly appreciated

Comment: Did you find solution on this?

Comment: Sadly no, I am still looking for proper and complete solution

Answer (score 1):

Please check SE Data Explorer ... maybe this one: https://data.stackexchange.com/magento/query/205459/all-tag-creators

Comment: I am little confused about is it showed my created tags during asking and editing question count or tags in which I created the usage guidance for that particular tag? if it shows the tags in which I created the usage guidance then I want to specifically view the tags in isolation which I created during asking and editing question I hope you got my point. Still `+1` for your effort